# Strange shift key issue and diagnosis

Tags: drivers, keyboard

**The setup**

- A wireless keyboard and mouse (Logitech)
- A backup wireless keyboard and mouse (generic)
- A normal intel windows desktop PC

**The problem**

The keyboard works fine for 6 months or so, and then, the SHIFT key behaves strangely. It will not work with some of the keys, in my case i notice it specifically with C key and the number 2 key
i.e. I cannot get a capital `C` using the shift key or the `@` symbol

It will work with the other keys but on occasion fail with some of them as well. for example, Ctrl + Shift + T to restore tab always showed a blank tab and i was worried that chrome was at fault , but then i realized that the Shift wasn't firing, and thus it was opening a new tab instead.

Using various keyboard tools (microsoft on-screen keyboard, keyboardtester.com) I've figured out the the shift key toggles it state rapidly and inconsistently.
[This article](https://www.techrepublic.com/forums/discussions/keyboard-shift-key-on-off-problem/) explains the situation very well, my situation is very similar except I know it's not a hardware issue. How?

Simple, i tried the same wireless keyboard on other computers, and it works flawlessly for months on end!!!

**Possible points of failure**

1. Hardware/keyboard chip - X
2. Motherboard/bios  ?
3. Drivers - X
4. Physical key contacts - X
5. Battery - X
6. Interfering software - ? have yet to test in safe mode.
7. Wireless signal interference - ? don't know how to test for this.
8. Static Buildup - ? don't know how to test for this as well

**Things I've tried**

- Replacing battery - no impact
- changing host machine - works on a different host, but not on this machine (so this narrows down the issue to this particular configuration)
- Update device driver - done, no impact, all the keyboards have the same microsoft HID keyboard device from 2006-06-21, version: 10.0.16299.15
- Using other keyboards on the machine, wired & wireless - works fine
- Removed the keycaps and cleaned the keyboard.
- Quit all background programs (side question is there a good app/script to terminate all tray apps?)
- Tried pressing and holding both shift keys for 10 seconds, and a combination of alt + ctrl as well, as recommended by other sources.

The *interesting thing* is this, that the first time this happened i replaced my generic wireless set with a logitech wireless set, and gave the older one to another team member to use (for whom it worked with no problems). Now the 2nd time it has happened with the new keyboard, I've given that to the team member as well, and taken the old one back, which now works well (who knows for how long).

I was hoping I could receive advice on what other possible points of failure might be given this situation. Any keyboard hardware experts out there who have ideas?

I know this is a trivial thing to think about, but it's intriguing that's why I'm trying to find the root cause.